# Dynamic Visualforce Components post back values

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

If I add an `Component.Apex.InputText` to a Visualforce page using dynamic Visualforce components how can I see the value that is entered in that component when the user submits the page back via a command button?

Page snippet:

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!dynamicPropertyControls}"/>
```

Controller snippet:

```
public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getDynamicPropertyControls() {
    Component.Apex.OutputPanel dynOutPanel= new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();

    Component.Apex.InputText textValue = new Component.Apex.InputText();
    textValue.value = 'Test';
    dynOutPanel.childComponents.add(textValue);

    return dynOutPanel;
}
```

So the user will see a text input with the value 'Test'. If they change the value and post the page back via a command button how can I get the changed value?

Do I need to maintain a list of dynamic controls that were added to the page in a member variable so they come back via view state?

I suspect it will probably be easier to completely change my approach to avoid the dynamic components and instead bind to a collection of custom objects. Still, how would you ever get the value back from a dynamic control, especially if it isn't bound to anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried following approach and it works for me.
VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="DynaCompCtrl">
<apex:form>
    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!DynamicPropertyControls}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class DynaCompCtrl{  
    public String myval {get;set;}

    public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getDynamicPropertyControls() {
       Component.Apex.OutputPanel dynOutPanel= new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();

       Component.Apex.InputText textValue = new Component.Apex.InputText();
       textValue.value = 'Test';
       textValue.expressions.value = '{!myval}';
       dynOutPanel.childComponents.add(textValue);

       return dynOutPanel;
    }    

    public void save() {
     system.debug('#########-'+myval);   
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. This does work, but I'm wondering if there is an approach that would be better suited for dynamic controls. With dynamic controls I could have any number of controls across a range of data types. It isn't practical to have hard coded properties for them to bind to. I guess I'm looking for dynamic binding properties to do with the dynamic controls.

Comment: @DanielBallinger what do you mean by dynamic controls? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Say you were calling a web service to determine which visualforce components to add to the page. You might have several InputText and a range of other controls based on the web service results. As these controls can vary dynamically in Apex, how do you get equally dynamic properties to bind to?

Comment: I've accepted this answer. In the absence of another example, I think the only way to get a value from a dynamic control is to bind it to something.

Comment: Hi Daniel - you may want to review the approach used here;[link](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Dynamic_Visualforce_Components)

Comment: Hi, i know this is almost an year old post, but i have a similar kind of a requirement. I am tying to achieve pagination using command buttons as dynamic components. but i want to return the value of the button number to my controller. Can anyone please help me?